# AngularJS Controllers not showing the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-controller

When user enter texts on textbox {{student.fullName()}} should be updated. But this is not working. Any help?

## Sample Applications

```
<div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "studentController">
    Enter first name: <input type= "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br/><br/>
    Enter last name: <input type= "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br/><br/>

    You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
</div>
<script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.Controller('studentController', function($scope){
        $scope.student = {
            firstName: "Mahesh",
            lastName: "Parashar",

            fullName: function() {
                var studentObject;
                studentObject = $scope.student;
                return studentObject.firstName+ " " + studentObject.lastName;
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: which angular js version you are using?

Comment: Case sensitive error.. Change C to c in controller definition and try

Comment: While the cause has been posted in the responses note that when things don't work first check your browser's console. You would have seen something like "Uncaught TypeError: mainApp.Controller is not a function".

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad Angular 1.4

Comment: The problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the lowercase `c` for `controller`

```
 mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope){
```

http://jsbin.com/besini/1/edit?html,css,console,output